# How to implement DRF in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to implement Dominant Resource Fairness (DRF) in Kubernetes? it has already been implemented in Apache mesos but I'm not make sure that it is possible in Kubernetes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculation of dominant resources in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524271/calculation-of-dominant-resources-in-kubernetes)