# Calculation of dominant resources in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to calculate dominant shares of resources in Kubernetes based on what Dominant Resource Fairness(DRF) does. How can I implement it in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific set patterns or guidelines for DRF in Kubernetes yet. The closest that you can get to it is by trying to manage compute resources in [containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) together with what the [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/) does.  You can also start if you fetch all the pod requests and node capacities using `kubectl`.

As a matter of fact, the [Kubernetes Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html) native scheduler does something similar to that, you can probably start by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/e9e8bb33ef9ad785473ded168bc85867dad4ee70/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/k8s).

If you don't want to use Kubernetes you can either use [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) or [YARN](https://hortonworks.com/blog/yarn-capacity-scheduler/) that implement DRF natively.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. Yes great, I will try to do what you mentioned.